# Django: redirect -> TypeError

Tags: python, django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**views.py**

```
def add_news(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            news = Bd.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
            return redirect(news)
    else:
        form = NewsForm()
    return render(request, 'bord/add_news.html', {'form': form})
```

**add_news.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block sidebar %}
{% include 'inc/_sidebar.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Добавление новости</h1>

<form action="{% url 'add_news' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Добавить новость</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего в модели Bd не указан метод get_absolute_url()

redirect(<цель>[, permanent=False] [, <значения ИRL-параметров>] ) - выпол­няет перенаправление по заданной цели, в качестве которой могут быть указаны:

- объект модели - вызов метода get_absolute_url() модели;
- имя маршрута (возможно, с указанием пространства имен) и набор
  значений ИRL-параметров - тогда адрес для перенаправления будет
  сформирован с применением обратного разрешения. значения
  URL-параметров могут быть указаны в вызове функции в виде как позиционных, так и именованных параметров;
- непосредственно заданный интернет-адрес.

Comment: def get_absolute_ulr(self):
        return reverse('view_news', kwargs={"news_id": self.pk}) - есть в модуле